# Django GIS' coveredby query returns wrong result

Tags: django, gis

There is an GIS coveredby query problem, the query returns a list of items that have a coordinates outside an area I have searched in, what's going on?

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon
from deals.models import Deal

x1, y1 = 37.446899, 55.693455
x2, y2 = 37.666626, 55.551165
area = Polygon(((x1, y1), (x2, y1), (x2, y2), (x1, y2), (x1, y1)))
qs = Deal.objects.filter(locations__coords__coveredby=area)

def count():
    ok, failed = 0, 0
    for item in qs.filter(locations__coords__isnull=False)[:20]:
        for loc in item.locations.all():
            lon = loc.longitude
            lat = loc.latitude
            if x1 <= lon <= x2 and y1 <= lat <= y2:
                ok += 1
            else:
                failed += 1
    return ok, failed

>>> ok, failed
Out[18]: (0, 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:

```
x1, y1 = 'left bottom corner of rectangle area'
x2, y2 = 'top right corner of rectangle area'
area = Polygon.from_bbox((x1, y1, x2, y2))
```

P.S. Cover this code with test to be sure :)